# EditText with a left and right border of given height

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-drawable

[image: edit text with stoke of given height]

How can i make my edit text have a background with that blue border at the bottom, left and right sides where left and right side border has (let say) a height of 2dp ?

I have tried using layelist but all it's hard to get left and right border like the one at the image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape >
        <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/>
       <size android:height="1dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/black"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

This is what i get

[image: bad output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi in most cases to have this type of background developers use 9.png graphics, you can generate background on this site.

http://android-holo-colors.com/

Answer (score 1):

I tried and this worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
            <size android:width="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- main color -->
    <item
        android:bottom="1.5dp"
        android:left="1.5dp"
        android:right="1.5dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- draw another block to cut-off the left and right bars -->
    <item android:bottom="5.0dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: android bottom, right, left and top are all offsets. item 1 doesn't have, item 2 has **item 3 which will appear at the top has a bottom offset of 5. but no left or right. further more take ito consideration the required height**

Answer (score 0):

try this way and set as background

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="0.5dp"
                android:color="@android:color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

set to your `Edittext` as background

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/editTextone"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edtbg"
    />
```